# Having error finding python module in MacOSX when trying to access a biopyhton module

Tags: python, macos

I have been trying to run few commands involving python but it returned the error as follows:

> from Bio import Entrez
>   ImportError: No module named Bio

I have biopython installed in

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

System python is in

> usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you have is loaded into the python3 library while the python you're apparently running is Python 2.7.  There may be issues trying to mix and match, but you COULD try to use the python3 module by adding the python3 library to your python 2.7 search path...  This is probably NOT a good idea though.  You could also try installing the Bio module into the 2.7 library with pip (python -m pip install Bio).  You could also try using python3 for the script you're writing.
try:

```
python3
```

and see if it starts a python interpreter.  If so, you should just use that as the python interpreter for your script.  From there you can try:

```
>>>from Bio import Entrez
```

to ensure it works.  If so, I'd suggest using python3 to create your script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. 
Accordingly, I have changed the python alias path to find python3:

```
echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.6” >> ~/.zprofile
```

This worked for me...This also keeps the /usr/local/bin/python  alive.